# How can an object of a vector access the vector elements

Tags: c++, object, vector, element

This is a program that simulates a simple resource gathering game
The robots gather resources from the map and move around randomly each one doing some actions.
My problem is that i want to access a vector from class map within the derivered class of robots "RescueBot" .
The program is written in multiple files, header.h , header.cpp, main.cpp

I have a vector of objects type "Robots" and an example of my header.h file:

```
class Map{
  private:
    char World[20][20]; // The size of Map is 20 x 20
    vector<Robots*>RobotsVector; 
  public:
    Map();
    vector<Robots*>*getRobotsVector();

}

   // I access the vector with getRobotsVector() which belongs to Map class but returns 
   // Robot objects. Done this so i can access Robot objects within the Map class.

class Robots
{
private:
    //some variables

public:
    //some functions
    virtual void movement()=0; // this is the function that handles the robots moves
    virtual void action()=0; // this is the function that handles the robots actions
}

class RescueBot:public Robots{
   void movement();
   void action();
 //some unique RescueBot stuff here
}
```

This is from the header.cpp file:

```
#include "header.h"
vector<Robots*>*Map::getRobotsVector(){return &RobotsVector;}

 //example of object creation and pushing into vector
void Map::creation(){
   for (int x=0;x<4;x++){
    getRobotsVector()->push_back(new RescueBot);
   }
}

void RescueBot::action(){
    //do stuff

 for(int i=0;i<Map::getRobotsVector()->size();i++){

       //Here is the problem. I cant get inside the for loop

      Map::getRobotsVector()->at(i)->setDamaged(false); //Changes a flag in other objects

   }
}
```

I Have tried making the Robots class derivered class of Map. After that when i run it the vector i access in RescueBot::action is empty, while the actual vector has objects in it.
If i dont make it derivered it doesnt compile.

How can i access the vector from within the RescueBot::action() ??

Comment: It cannot, unless you pass the vector to the constructor of the object, or set a pointer to the vector on each object that you add to that vector. Generally, neither one is a particularly good idea.

Comment: Your thinking about it wrong. If RescueBot needs to modify Map, then it needs to take Map in as a parameter, either in the constructor or in the action command (personally, i'd favor the action command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have no `Map` instances.

The way you're calling it currently would only work if the `getRobotsVector` method were `static`, but **you don't want that**.

The reason it works when you make the `Robots` class a derived class of `Map` is because `Map::getRobotsVector()` would just mean you want to invoke the `getRobotsVector` method on the instance that the `RescueBot::action` function is operating on.

The solution is to pass an instance of a Map to your `action` functions by reference.

This is what your action function would look like then:

```
void RescueBot::action(Map& map) {
    // Do whatever you want with the map here.
    // For example:
    map.getRobotsVector()->at(i)->setDamaged(false);
}
```

Comment: Since the OP probably will have only 1 map active at a time, why wouldn't he want to make `getRobotsVector` `static`? It seems like a perfectly correct solution IMHO.

Comment: @PawełStawarz It's analogous to a singleton, which is a terrible thing to have for [some pretty good reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

Comment: I dont have only 1 action function. I have 3 via polymorphism. When i change my rescuebot::action i get this error at the compiler :
<< prototype for 'void RescueBot::action(Map&)' does not match any in class 'RescueBot'|>>

Comment: i tryed it the static way too but i get an error at header.cpp at this 
"vector<Robots*>*Map::getRobotsVector(){return &RobotsVector;}"
The error is: undefined reference to `Map::RobotsVector' 
Do i need to change my getRobotsVector function to make it work ?

Comment: All your `action` methods should take a `Map&` then.